# Model as a variable

Tags: php, laravel

I use switch to execute the code I want depending on the model. Is there a way to immediately substitute the model into the code from the variable that comes to me to avoid repeating the code 3 times?

```
switch ($data['model_type']) {
    case Review::class:
        $record = Review::query()
            ->where('id', $data['model_id'])
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->first();
        break;
    case Question::class:
        $record = Question::query()
            ->where('id', $data['model_id'])
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->first();
        break;
    case Answer::class:
       $record = Answer::query()
            ->where('id', $data['model_id'])
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->first();
        break;
    default:
        return $this->jsonError('404', 404);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this shoud works:

```php
if(!in_array($data['model_type'], [
    Review::class, 
    Question::class, 
    Answer::class]
){
    return $this->jsonError('404', 404);
}


$record = $data['model_type']::query()
            ->where('id', $data['model_id'])
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->first();
```

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: @Sergey you can even export the `if()` logic in your validation

Answer (score 2):

You can put the query in a variable in your switch and execute the duplicate code after the switch:

```
switch ($data['model_type']) {
            case Review::class:
                $query = Review::query();
                break;
            case Question::class:
                $query = Question::query();
                break;
            case Answer::class:
               $query = Answer::query();
                break;
            default:
                return $this->jsonError('404', 404);
        }

$record = $query->where('id', $data['model_id'])
        ->whereNotNull('published_at')
        ->first();
```